# Using subprocess or alike to redirect the Standard Output of a shell command to a dynamic directory/filename

Tags: python

I have been coding for a few months and hit a wall.
The following code simply prints a menu and runs a few shell commands and outputs these to the screen.
What i'd like to do is send the output of the menu 1 options to a "workspace".
I'm calling a workspace a user inputted directory whereby when a shell command is executed it saves the the std in as a file to that respective directory.
I will have over 50 different command that will be executed eventually and i want them to all be neatly stored in the relative directories.
Currently using Python 3.4

So far my code can, request user input for a workspace, which inturn creates a relative directory.
What I need to is get a file to be outputted.

```
#Imports
import os
import subprocess


#Set Globals for Workspace to 0
workspace = 0
absolute_path = 0


#Initally clear the screen
os.system('clear')

#Define Option 0 - Create a Workspace
def workspace_menu():
    print ("Enter the name of the Workspace or type 'q' or 'quit' to return to the main menu")
    print ("")
    workspace_input = input(":")
    if workspace_input in ("q", "quit"):
        os.system('clear')
    else:
#Define the current working directoy (__file__)
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    relative_path = 'workspaces/'
    joined_path = os.path.join(script_dir, relative_path)
    os.chdir(joined_path)
    if os.path.exists(workspace_input):
        print ("Directory already Exists! - Try a different name")
        input("Press any key to Return to the Main Menu")
        os.system('clear')
    else:
        make_path = os.makedirs(workspace_input)
        absolute_path = joined_path + workspace_input
        global absolute_path
        absolute_path = absolute_path
        global workspace
        workspace = 1
        print ("Workspace created!"), absolute_path
        input("Press any Key to Continue")
        os.system('clear')
        return

#Define the Main Menu
def menu():
    print(" 0) Add a Workspace")
    print(" 1) System Tasks")
    print("11) Exit")


#Define System Tasks
def system_tasks():
    os.system('clear')
    print(" 1) Display Local Network information")
    print(" 5) Back")
    system_tasks_answer = int(input(":"))
    if system_tasks_answer == 1:
        print("The Local Network Configuration of this OS are:")
        print("")
        ifconfig = subprocess.call(['/sbin/ifconfig'])
        dns = subprocess.call(['cat', '/etc/resolv.conf'])
        print("")
        print(workspace)
        lni_menu = input("Press any Key to Continue")
        system_tasks()
        os.system('clear')
    elif system_tasks_answer == 5:
        os.system('clear')


loop=True

while loop:
    print (menu())
    mm_answer = int(input(":"))
    if mm_answer ==0:
        workspace_menu()
    elif mm_answer ==1:
        system_tasks()
    elif mm_answer ==11:
        break
    else:
        input("You did not give a valid answer, press any key to try again") 
        os.system('clear')
```

Comment: BTW. there is a neat package which makes it really easy to create prompt oriented programs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.call`'s `stdout` argument to run a command and redirect its standard output to a file. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) states

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are PIPE, DEVNULL, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None. [...]

This means, if you pass a file object (returned by `open()`) to `stdout`, it will use this file object to redirect the standard output. Everything that the sub-process writes to its standard output is written to the file object.

For example to redirect the output of the command `ls /tmp` to a file `output` you can write:

```
with open("output", "wb") as f:
    return_code = subprocess.call(["ls", "/tmp"], stdout=f)
```

[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would you be able to elaborate a little on it please?

Comment: The answer should be more verbose now.